# Ola Hallengren - Parallel Backup Jobs failing on SINGLE_USER DB - 'Database is in transition' [952]

Tags: jobs, ola-hallengren, error-log

I'm using Ola's `DatabasesInParallel` option for "multi-threaded" execution. Last night a db was temporarily placed into `SINGLE_USER` for an application-based archive process and it caused all 5 threads of my parallel backup jobs to fail when attempting to backup the log of this database.

If it were any other type of failure the job would log it and continue it's execution. In this case, each parallel job tried to back it up and each one failed immediately, skipping log backups on hundreds of databases.

Fortunately, they were all backed up again 15 minutes later with no issues, but it was quite alarming to have our on-call resource get woken up at 3am.

The error at the very bottom of each job's log file is as follows:

```
Msg 952, Sev 16, State 1, Line 1:  
Database 'FAKEDBNAME' is in transition. Try the statement later. [SQLSTATE 42000]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed the question here, are you asking if this is a bug? It seems like the expected behavior.

Comment: I think it's a bug. If a single DB is offline or SINGLE_USER why should all backups be halted for all parallel jobs versus just skipping the offline DB?